# British pound sign not displayed

Tags: c++, string

I have a program that contains a list that I check against.
The list parses ok on my machine, but fails on another.
It is failing at the £ (british pound) sign.

```
string whiteList = "0123456789 $/£-.";
size_t failPos = dataToCheck.find_first_not_of (whiteList, 0);
```

When I try on the other machine, it displays ú and therefore fails validation.

Is there something I can do in C++ (convert to unicode or something) to get round this?
I've tried converting to wstring, but it doesn't know what wstring is (I'm using VS2003).
According to some sites, I just need to `#include <string>`

Comment: Check [C localization library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/LC_categories). Not sure it would affect display of this characte correctly. A particular [codepage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) setting might be necessary to display it on console (I assume you're referring to this use case)

Comment: Converting a program to use wide characters isn't just a matter of replacing `string` with `wstring`. Where does the data inside `dataToCheck` come from? Is it in a file? What is the encoding?

Comment: What is the encoding of your source file? If it is not unicode you may have different (default) codepages on your machines (happens most often on Windows) treating the non-unicode pound sign codepoint differently.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments.  These make sense. dataToCheck comes from an external source and is a char* which I create a string from.  The data then goes back to another function, which annoyingly takes a char*.  On my machine, I can just use the c_str(), but this doesn't work for wstring.  I'll keep digging

Comment: What exactly is your problem with wstring? VS2003 should provide it according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3s3k55(v=vs.71).aspx). But even if you use wstring you need to set/use the correct locale, then convert to utf-16. After processing convert back again.